# anylogic- color on the left side of the resource pool block at model runtime

Tags: anylogic

I created two service and resource pool blocks for pressing and packaging processes in the manufacturing line. Now I want to interpret the block's status at the model runtime.  What does each color on the left side of the resource pool block mean at the model runtime?

This is not all explained very clearly in the anylogic help or maybe I could not find it. anyLogic help says: "Shows the block's overall load throughout the whole operating time". But this explanation is not enough for me. I want to know  what does each color mean separately?

Does the red color represent the highest utilization and the green color indicate the least utilization?

Many thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color coding visually shows the utilization of the ressource pool. The utilization is calculated internally as documented in the AnyLogic help:

> utilization(): Returns utilization of this resource pool. The returned value is the mean over all individual unit utilization, calculated from the most recent resetStats() call up to current time. If the number and availability of resource units is defined by a schedule, utilization will be calculated only for the operating hours of the corresponding resource unit.

The color coding of the utilization of the ressourcePool element in AnyLogic is as follows:

- 0 % - 19%: blue
- 20% - 39%: green
- 40% - 59%: yellow
- 60% - 79%: orange
- 80% - 100%: red

Here are all color codings in the same order as above:

[image: Stati Colors of Ressource Pool]

Comment: Hi Florian! So in this case (resource pool),  the red color indicates the desired situation. Is it true?

Comment: That depends on your goals. If you have the goal to maximise utilisation (best use of existing resources, "saving money") then yes, red is what you want. If your goal is to avoid a very high utilisation in order to avoid a bottleneck for your process or in order to keep idle capacity for peak times, then you might be happier with a blue/green/yellow colour.